# IE9 CSS Hack - What Properties Don't Work?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'd like to use the `IE9` hack in my CSS, instead of having a separate conditional stylesheet.

These don't seem to work though.

```
.cover-header .cover-intro {
  text-align: center \9;
  font: 0/0 a \9;  
}

.cover-header .cover-intro:before {
  content: ' ' \9;
  display: inline-block \9;
  vertical-align: middle \9;
  height: 100% \9;
}

.cover-header .cover-intro .cover-heading {
  width: 100% \9;
  display: inline-block \9;
  vertical-align: middle \9;
  font: 16px/1 'Lato', Helvetica, sans-serif \9;
}
```

I wanted to know what properties are supported with this hack, and if the above are, why aren't they being applied to the IE9 browser?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the real problem? No hacks needed.

Comment: Using flexbox on the site, this was a fallback solution that centered my `.cover-heading` element vertically.

Comment: you can put these rules above the flexbox's ones. IE9 takes these, other browsers which know flexbox takes flexbox's ones.

Comment: Ahh, makes sense. What do I do with the `:before` property, as that doesn't exist outside of my IE stylesheet?

Comment: makes `:before` any problems in other browsers? Sure, you need that just for IE9, but do nothing bad in others. Can be interperted by them too.

Answer (score 3):

The `\9` hack should work with all properties. The problem here is that you have a space preceding the `\9`, which breaks the hack.

Removing the space should fix it. Doing so might make your CSS a little less readable, but unfortunately it's absolutely necessary in this case. In properties with space-separated values, such as the `font` shorthand, only the space directly preceding the `\9` should be removed; the rest should be kept as they are part of the property value.

```
.cover-header .cover-intro {
  text-align: center\9;
  font: 0/0 a\9;
}

.cover-header .cover-intro:before {
  content: ' '\9;
  display: inline-block\9;
  vertical-align: middle\9;
  height: 100%\9;
}

.cover-header .cover-intro .cover-heading {
  width: 100%\9;
  display: inline-block\9;
  vertical-align: middle\9;
  font: 16px/1 'Lato', Helvetica, sans-serif\9;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Chekout following List of CSS hacks for different versions of IE

**CSS**

```
#hack{
    color:red; /* All browsers */
    color:red !important;/* All browsers but IE6 */
    _color:red; /* Only works in IE6 */
    *color:red; /* IE6, IE7 */
    +color:red;/* Only works in IE7*/
    *+color:red; /* Only works in IE7 */
    color:red\9; /* IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9 */
    color:red\0; /* IE8, IE9 */
    color:red\9\0;/*Only works in IE9*/
}
```

Make sure you write hacked css property after the normal css property for eg

```
.div {
    color: #f00;
    color: #000\9\0; /*Only works in IE9*/
}
```

Comment: Down voters please consider adding comments. if you think that answer is not correct or not useful to OP.